# [Jersey][Jackson][JPA] Link entity to existing and persist only if not exist

Tags: hibernate, rest, jakarta-ee, jersey, jackson

Here is the Video entity :

```
public class Video {
    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="title", length=100, unique=true)
    private String title;

    @ManyToMany(
        targetEntity=Tag.class,
        cascade={CascadeType.ALL},
        fetch = FetchType.EAGER
    )
    @JoinTable(
        name="video_tag",
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="video_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="tag_id")
    )
    private Set<Tag> tags = new HashSet<Tag>(0);
}
```

Video entity contains tags :

```
public class Tag {
    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="name", nullable=false, unique=true)
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "tags")
    private Set<Video> videos = new HashSet<Video>(0);
}
```

Now, I would like to add new Video entity by POST request, So I use Jersey and Jackson to marshall / unmarshall json to entities :

```
@POST
@Path("/")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response post(Video video) throws Exception  {   
    VideoService videoService = new VideoService();
    videoService.persist(video);
    return Response.ok(video).build();
}
```

I use this POST request to add a new video :

```
POST http://localhost:8080/project/video
Headers :
Content-Type application/json
Body :
{"tags":[{"name":"tag1"}, {"name":"tag2"}],"title":"video42"}
```

If tag1 and tag2 doesnt' exist all is good.
But if a tag already exist, the behavior I want is to add only tag that does not exist. Here I have an error on first Tag "Duplicate field".

I think there is something to do before :
    videoService.persist(video);

Answer (score 0):

As JPA cannot know if the tag already exists you will have to query the database/entitymanager for the Tag with the given name first. Otherwise JPA will try to persist a new Tag along with the new video. This will fail if a Tag with the given name already exists, as `Tag.name` is defined as `unique=true`

So search for the Tag with the given name and if this tag exists set it on the Video and everything should work as expected.